# Unity IAP - how to restore my Android purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase

I made an Android payment system with IAP and it is currently registered in the App Store. However, a customer paid for the product and used it, but when I turned on the app again, the payment disappeared and the payment was proceeded again, and the window said, "It's an item I already have," and I couldn't pay.

So we need to add payment restoration function, but the official document and googling don't have an accurate restoration method. The only way to find it is old ways and errors I need to add a restoration function as soon as possible. How can I do this? I added the corresponding payment code below UNI.T version is 2021.3.3f1

Also, I added a script to the IAP button using OnPurchaseComplete without IStoreListener and proceeded with the payment, and I would like to recover it. They're all non-consumable products.

IAPScript:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing.Security;


public class IAPScript : GenericSingleton<IAPScript> 
{
    public string ChapterID_01 = "hisshow_vr_ani_01";
    public string ChapterID_02 = "hisshow_vr_ani_02";
    public string ChapterID_03 = "hisshow_vr_ani_03";
    public string ChapterID_04 = "hisshow_vr_ani_04";
    public string ChapterID_05 = "hisshow_vr_ani_05";
    public string ChapterID_06 = "hisshow_vr_ani_06";
    public string AllChapterID = "hisshow_vr_ani_package";
    public string PilgrID = "hisshow_vr_360_package";


    //Code for activating the corresponding commodity button
    public AdventurePurchaseManager AdventurePurchaseManager;
    public PilgrimagePurchassManager PilgrimagePurchassManager;
    //


    private void Start()
    {
        /*PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Cash1900_01");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Cash1900_02");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Cash1900_03");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Cash1900_05");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Cash1900_06");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Cash7900");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Cash3900");*/
        Debug.Log("IAPScript");
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        AdventurePurchaseManager = obj.transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetComponent<AdventurePurchaseManager>();
        PilgrimagePurchassManager = obj.transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(3).GetComponent<PilgrimagePurchassManager>();

    }



    public void OnPurchaseComplete(Product product)
    {
        if (product.definition.id == ChapterID_01)
        {
            Debug.Log("챕터1 결제 완료");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash1900_01", "buy");
            AdventurePurchaseManager.SelectOpen_Chapter();

        }

        if (product.definition.id == ChapterID_02)
        {
            Debug.Log("챕터2 결제 완료");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash1900_02", "buy");
            AdventurePurchaseManager.SelectOpen_Chapter();
        }

        if (product.definition.id == ChapterID_03)
        {
            Debug.Log("챕터3 결제 완료");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash1900_03", "buy");
            AdventurePurchaseManager.SelectOpen_Chapter();
        }

        if (product.definition.id == ChapterID_04)
        {
            /*Debug.Log("챕터3 결제 완료");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash1900_04", "buy");
            AdventurePurchaseManager.SelectOpen_Chapter();
            CodelessIAPStoreListener.Instance.StoreController.InitiatePurchase(ChapterID_04);*/
        }

        if (product.definition.id == ChapterID_05)
        {
            Debug.Log("챕터5 결제 완료");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash1900_05", "buy");
            AdventurePurchaseManager.SelectOpen_Chapter();
        }

        if (product.definition.id == ChapterID_06)
        {
            Debug.Log("챕터6 결제 완료");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash1900_06", "buy");
            AdventurePurchaseManager.SelectOpen_Chapter();
        }

        if (product.definition.id == AllChapterID)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash7900", "buy");
            Debug.Log("올 챕터 결제 완료");
            AdventurePurchaseManager.AllChapter();
        }

        if (product.definition.id == PilgrID)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Cash3900", "buy");
            Debug.Log("성지순례 모든 챕터 결제 완료");
            PilgrimagePurchassManager.Opne_All();
        }

    }

    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason reason)
    {
        Debug.Log("결제 실패");
    }

}
```

AdventurePurchaseManager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

public class AdventurePurchaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AdventureChapter[] chapters;
    public GameObject Package;
    public IAPButton iAPButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        chapters = GetComponentsInChildren<AdventureChapter>();
        Package = transform.parent.Find("Package").gameObject;
        iAPButton = Package.GetComponent<IAPButton>();

        if (transform.parent.parent.name != "SelectVr")
        {
            iAPButton = Package.GetComponent<IAPButton>();
            iAPButton.onPurchaseComplete.AddListener(IAPScript.Instance.OnPurchaseComplete);
            iAPButton.onPurchaseFailed.AddListener(IAPScript.Instance.OnPurchaseFailed);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash7900"))
        {
            Open_AllChapter();
            Debug.Log("PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Cash7900)");
        }
        else
        {
            SelectOpen_Chapter();
        }
      
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine("delay_OnEnable");
    }


    public void AllChapter()
    {
        StartCoroutine("delay_OnEnable");
    }

    public void SelectOpen_Chapter()
    {
        StartCoroutine("delay_SelectOpenChapter");
    }

    IEnumerator delay_OnEnable()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash7900"))
        {
            Open_AllChapter();
        }
        else
        {
            SelectOpen_Chapter();
        }

    }

    IEnumerator delay_SelectOpenChapter()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);

        bool[] checkBuyChapter = new bool[6];

        chapters[3].SetFree();
        checkBuyChapter[3] = true;

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash1900_01"))
        {
            chapters[0].SetPurchase();
            checkBuyChapter[0] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chapters[0].SetLock();
            checkBuyChapter[0] = false;
        }

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash1900_02"))
        {
            chapters[1].SetPurchase();
            checkBuyChapter[1] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chapters[1].SetLock();
            checkBuyChapter[1] = false;
        }


        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash1900_03"))
        {
            chapters[2].SetPurchase();
            checkBuyChapter[2] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chapters[2].SetLock();
            checkBuyChapter[2] = false;
        }

        /* if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash1900_04"))
         {
             chapters[4].SetPurchase();
             checkBuyChapter[4] = true;
         }
         else
         {
             chapters[4].SetLock();
             checkBuyChapter[4] = false;
         }*/

      /*  if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash1900_04"))
        {
            chapters[3].SetFree();
            checkBuyChapter[3] = true;

        }*/



        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash1900_05"))
        {
            chapters[4].SetPurchase();
            checkBuyChapter[4] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chapters[4].SetLock();
            checkBuyChapter[4] = false;
        }


        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash1900_06"))
        {
            chapters[5].SetPurchase();
            checkBuyChapter[5] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chapters[5].SetLock();
            checkBuyChapter[5] = false;
            Debug.Log("test");
        }

        bool check = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < checkBuyChapter.Length; i++)
        {
            if (checkBuyChapter[i] == false)
            {
                check = false;
            }
        }

        if (check)
        {
            Package.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Package.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

    }

    public void Open_AllChapter()
    {
        foreach (var chapter in chapters)
        {
            if (chapter.myIndex == 3)
            {
                chapter.SetFree();
            }
            else
            {
                chapter.SetPurchase();
            }
        }
        Package.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

AdventureChapter:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

public class AdventureChapter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int myIndex;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject dim;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject paid;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject sell;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject free;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject locked;
    [SerializeField] private Button button;

    [SerializeField] private IAPButton IAPButton;


    private void Awake()
    {
        myIndex = transform.GetSiblingIndex();

        dim = transform.Find("Dim").gameObject;
        paid = transform.Find("Paid").gameObject;
        sell = transform.Find("Sell").gameObject;
        free = transform.Find("Free").gameObject;
        locked = transform.Find("Locked").gameObject;
        button = GetComponent<Button>();

        if (transform.parent.parent.parent.name != "SelectVr")
        {
            IAPButton = locked.GetComponent<IAPButton>();
            IAPButton.onPurchaseComplete.AddListener(IAPScript.Instance.OnPurchaseComplete);
            IAPButton.onPurchaseFailed.AddListener(IAPScript.Instance.OnPurchaseFailed);
        }

    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {

    }

    public void SetFree()
    {
        dim.SetActive(false);
        paid.SetActive(false);
        sell.SetActive(false);
        free.SetActive(true);
        locked.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = true;
    }
    public void SetLock()
    {
        dim.SetActive(true);
        paid.SetActive(false);
        sell.SetActive(true);
        free.SetActive(false);
        locked.SetActive(true);
        button.interactable = false;
    }
    public void SetPurchase()
    {
        dim.SetActive(false);
        paid.SetActive(true);
        sell.SetActive(false);
        free.SetActive(false);
        locked.SetActive(false);
        button.interactable = true;
    }
}
```

PilgrimagePurchassManager:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.U2D;
 using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

 public class PilgrimagePurchassManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
    [SerializeField] private Image[] pgImages;
    [SerializeField] private Button[] pgButtons;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject Package;
    [SerializeField] private string[] pgWordIndex;

    public SpriteAtlas Pilgrimage;

    private IAPButton IAPButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        pgImages = new Image[transform.childCount];
        pgButtons = new Button[transform.childCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            pgImages[i] = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>();
            pgButtons[i] = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>();
        }

        Package = transform.parent.GetChild(4).gameObject;
        if (transform.parent.parent.parent.name != "VideoExit")
        {
            IAPButton = Package.GetComponent<IAPButton>();
            IAPButton.onPurchaseComplete.AddListener(IAPScript.Instance.OnPurchaseComplete);
            IAPButton.onPurchaseFailed.AddListener(IAPScript.Instance.OnPurchaseFailed);
        }


        pgWordIndex = new string[] {"02","05","04","03","16", "18", "22", "21", "19", "20", "10", "11" ,"09", "07" ,"23" ,"08", "06", "12", "13", "14", "15", "17" };
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Cash3900"))
        {
            Opne_All();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pgButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < 4)
                {
                    pgButtons[i].enabled = true;
                    pgButtons[i].interactable = true;
                    pgImages[i].sprite = Pilgrimage.GetSprite($"Pilgrimage_spot_{pgWordIndex[i]}_unlock");
                }
                else
                {
                    pgButtons[i].enabled = false;
                    pgButtons[i].interactable = false;

                    pgButtons[i].enabled = true;
                    pgButtons[i].enabled = false;
                    pgImages[i].sprite = Pilgrimage.GetSprite($"Pilgrimage_spot_{pgWordIndex[i]}_lock");
                }
            }
            Package.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }



    public void Opne_All()
    {
        StartCoroutine("Delay_OPenAll");
    }

    IEnumerator Delay_OPenAll()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);
        for (int i = 0; i < pgButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            pgButtons[i].enabled = true;
            pgButtons[i].interactable = true;
            pgImages[i].sprite = Pilgrimage.GetSprite($"Pilgrimage_spot_{pgWordIndex[i]}_unlock");
        }
        Package.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }    

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the unity codeless IAP.
Here is the link documentation/tutorial for codeless IAP. You can also add the restore button with the help of codeless IAP.
https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@3.1/manual/UnityIAPCodelessIAP.html